# Azure data factory - rest copy activity additional header not working

Tags: azure, http-headers, azure-data-factory, setcookie

I'm working with an api which requires header "cookie" for authentication (sap).
In the first step I get the cookieID (web activity, works fine) and then I want to pass as it as a header in the copy activity using a rest source dataset: Additional headers name:cookie value:@activity('GetCookie').output.ADFWebActivityResponseHeaders['Set-Cookie']. But i'm getting a 401 authentication error.

When I pass the same cookie output to Web activity, it works fine. (The only difference is that the section is named Headers not additional headers.)
When I choose in the copy activity http source (instead of rest source) it works fine as well - same cookie, except additional header is created as a string not filled in fields.

Is there a reason why it would work in Http source and Web activity but would not work in Rest source? The rest dataset is connected to a linked service which is anonymous (I tried linked service with basic authentication with no difference)

In debug log I can see that the cookie header is used and it is correct. Because of pagination I need to use the rest source.

[input printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVcFv.png)

Comment: REST connector only supports response in JSON. Check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest?tabs=data-factory#rest-as-source) for more details.

Comment: I'm fine with that. But I'm not getting any response, just a 401 error. Maybe I dont understand how does it relate to my problem - i'm not trying to setup an accept header, I'm adding a cookie header and from the input printscreen it seems that it is getting send.

Answer (score 0):

So turned out that cookie header in the rest copy activity (HttpClientHandler UseCookies) is not used when it runs even though in the debug code you can see it as it being send.
I did not found a way around it, I had to use http source and handle pagination myself.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).